# Advanced Preprocesor Tokenization in C

Tags: c, macros, token, c-preprocessor, pic

I'm having problem building **C** macro for my PIC. It's the same for other C-based system's, so non-PIC **C** experts are also more than welcome.

Lets assume that I have defined my LED_1 pin :

```
#define LED_1 A1    //A1 as output for LED_1
```

So if I want to light a LED I would write:

```
PORTAbits.RA1 = 1;
```

And if I would like to do it using my LED_1 definition I have to add two more macros:

```
#define change_PORT_(var) PORTAbits.R##var
#define change_PORT(var) change_PORT_(var
```

And to use it:

```
change_PORT(LED_1) = 1;
```

And it works like a charm. But the problem is that in definitions above I have

> PORT **A** bits.##var

So what if I want to change PORTB values? I would have to build separate macros for PORTs A and B. But it's not even close to be a robust solution.
And I came up with an idea which, I don't know why, doesnt work.

```
#define LED_1 A1
#define LED_2 B1

#define __A1 A   //This would be defined for all PORTA's pins such as A2,A3,A4 etc
#define __B1 B

#define ___change_PORT(var,var2)    PORT##var2 bits.R##var
#define __change_PORT(var,var2)   ___change_PORT(var,var2)
#define _change_PORT(var)    __change_PORT(var,__##var) // creating e.g. __A1
#define change_PORT(var)   _change_PORT(var)
```

And when I try to run this:

```
change_PORT(LED_1);
```

The compiler changes **__##var** to **___A1** but it never changes **__A1** to **A** so this MACRO doesn't work as it supposed to.

I spent a lot of time trying to fix it so I'd appreciate any help :)

> ---
>
> **EDIT::**
>
> ---

I might have found a solution to my problem:
(LAT is just another register name, but it works same as PORT, so this name-change is irrelevant)

```
#define ___PORTchange(var,var2) PORT##var2##bits.R##var
#define __PORTchange(var,var2)  ___PORTchange(var,var2)
#define CHANGE_TO_PORT_NAME(var) ___##var
#define _PORTchange(var)    __PORTchange(var,CHANGE_TO_PORT_NAME(var))
#define PORTchange(var) _PORTchange(var)
```

but I get a compiler error:

> 100:   PORTAbits.RA0 = 1;
>                    ^ (374) missing basic type; int assumed (warning)
>                ^ (983) storage class redeclared
>                ^ (984) type redeclared
>                ^ (239) identifier "PORTAbits" redefined (from line 3900)
>                ^ (314) ";" expected

So no it does substitute it correctly but I get a compiler warning telling me that I redefine PORTAbits which I cannot understand. I just wanted preprocessor to change **PORTchange(var)** to **PORTxbits.Rvar** where x is A or B. But instead it seems that I'm redeclaring something.

I don't get it.

Comment: Could you give a minimal but complete code? (And state what you are expecting/wanting as well as what you get.)

Comment: I change the code after edit mark. And my question now is why my macro doesnt just substitute one text with other but insted it tries to redefine some predefined structs(PORTAbits).

Comment: From the errors you are citing, the context of use is important.

Comment: Thanks for this comment. Indeed the context was important ;) It seems that the version of code after edit in my post work well. I use Hi-tech C compiler so if anyone happens to have similar problem with it I guess that would be a solution. @AProgrammer thanks a lot for your help :)

Comment: Oops, thought I had the answer - thought it was atmel for a moment, not PIC. I deleted my post.

Answer (score 2):

If I preprocess (tried with several gcc versions and sun cc)

```
#define LED_1 A1
#define LED_2 B1

#define __A1 AX
#define __B1 BX

#define ___change_PORT(var,var2)    PORT##var2##bits.R##var
#define __change_PORT(var,var2)   ___change_PORT(var,var2)
#define _change_PORT(var)    __change_PORT(var,__##var)
#define change_PORT(var)   _change_PORT(var)

change_PORT(LED_1);
change_PORT(LED_2);
```

I get

```
PORTAXbits.RA1;
PORTBXbits.RB1;
```

which is apparently what you are wanting.  A bug in your compiler?

Comment: I found a partial solution and edited my post. @AProgrammer can you tell what's the problem now? Or even better what's the solution ;)